# Swift - Firebase Model

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I find myself stuck upon the implementation of a model for getting data from a firebase database.

I'm not sure what I've done so far is correct but as far as my knowledge of swift is concerned (I'm new to swift) I think I've followed the right path.

So I have a collection view which get the data from a firebase database.
The database structure is like so:

```
-SwimManager
--SwimmingPools
---SwimPoolName 1
-----Capacity: "2000"
-----PhotoUrl: "https//www.test"
---SwimPoolName 2
-----Capacity: "3000"
-----PhotoUrl: "https//www.test"
```

I'll show the code for the view controller, the model and the cell.

Here's my ViewController:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
var swimRef = Database.database().reference().child("SwimmingPools")
var swimmingPools = [SwimmingPool]()
verride func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self

    getSwimPoolInfo()
}
func getSwimPoolInfo() {
    fishRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let swimNameFb = snap.key
            let value = snap.value
            let swim = Fish(swimName: swimNameFb, photoUrl: "")
            self.swimmingPools.append(swim)
            // Not sure how to add the picture
        }
    }
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "SwimCell", for: indexPath) as? SwimCell {
        let swim: SwimminPool!

            swim = swimmingPools[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(swim)
            return cell
    } else {
    return UICollectionViewCell()
```

Model:

```
class SwimmingPool {
  private var _swimName: String!
  private var _photourl: String!
  private var _capacity: String!

 var swimName: String {
      if _swimName == nil {
          _swimName = ""
      }
      return _swimName
   }
...............
    init(swimName: String, photoUrl: String) {
       self._SwimName = swimName
       self._photourl = photoUrl
   }
 func getData() {
//perform action the get the data from the single swimmingPool (e.g. swimPoolName 1)
 }
}
```

And finally, here's the cell:

```
class SwimCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var swimThumb: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var swimNameLbl: UILabel!

var swim: SwimmingPool!



func configureCell(_ swim: SwimmingPool) {

    self.swim = swim
    swimNameLbl.text = self.swim.swimName.capitalized
    var url = URL(string: self.swim.photoUrl)
    if url == nil {
        url = URL(string: "")
    }
    swimThumb.sd_setImage(with: url)

}
```

}

In the Viewcontroller the func getSwimPooInfo is triggered after viewDidLoad and so the array swimminPools is empty... Honestly it seems I cannot figure where my mistake is....

Thx!

Comment: do you have a reloadData() somewhere after your dataSource is populated from Firebase so the collection view knows to update itself? Also, * fishRef* is undefined.

Comment: i defined it actually just forgot to add it here... anyway i've just fixed it... the code is working... i've inverted numberOfItemsInSection and numberOfSections... this why it was not working.... more stupid is the error the more i loose my mind.. :D

Comment: Good good. In the future doing a tad more troubleshooting before posting would help us to help you; stating *so the array swimminPools is empty* led me in the wrong direction thinking it was a Firebase reference issue, not an tableView delegate method issue! lol. Closing this since you fixed it... go you!

Comment: i know you are right.... it was driving me crazy too... since it was hours i was trying to figure... and probably few of my answers were not much sense.... sorry! and thx you all for  the help! :)